# iterm2+ohmyzsh: stray characters on terminal from the previous command

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Sometimes the commands are persisted in the terminal if I use the up arrow key to re-run the command.
Using backspace doesn't clean the whole terminal as seen in the screenshot.
`git` command can be seen existing multiple times.

This sometimes issue is seen even when the pervious command is edited, cursor becomes invisible and editing becomes impossible.

I am on Catalina.

zsh: stable 5.8 (bottled), HEAD

[image]

Comment: Can you find a way to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: yes i can.
generally whenever when its a long line then this behavior occurs

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same behavior with iTerm2 3.4.3 and an up to date Oh My Zsh. Can you share a precise procedure to reproduce this problem ?